# A determinant involving the cotangent function

Tags: nt.number-theory, special-functions, permutations, determinants, roots-of-unity

Let $n>1$ be odd.  In my 2019 preprint [*On some determinants involving the tangent function*](http://arxiv.org/abs/1901.04837), I proved that
$$\det\left[\tan\pi\frac{aj+bk}n\right]_{1\le j,k\le n-1}=\left(\frac{-ab}n\right)n^{n-2}$$
for any integers $a$ and $b$ with $\gcd(ab,n)=1$, where $(\frac{\cdot}n)$ denotes the Jacobi symbol; in particular,
$$\det\left[\tan\pi\frac{j-k}n\right]_{1\le j,k\le n-1}=n^{n-2}.$$

Note that
$$\tan\pi x=\frac{2\sin\pi x}{2\cos\pi x}=i\frac{1-e^{2\pi ix}}{1+e^{2\pi i x}}.$$
So I actually evaluated the determinant
$$\det\left[\frac{1-\zeta^{j-k}}{1+\zeta^{j-k}}\right]_{1\le j,k\le n-1}$$
with $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/n}$. For $j,k=1,\ldots,n-1$ let's define
$$f(j,k)=\begin{cases}\cot\pi\frac{j-k}n&\text{if}\ j\not=k,\\0&\text{if}\ j=k.\end{cases}\label{1}\tag{$*$}$$
When $j\not=k$, we have
$$f(j,k)=-i\frac{1+\zeta^{j-k}}{1-\zeta^{j-k}}$$
Thus
\begin{align*}\det[f(j,k)]_{1\le j,k\le n-1}=&\sum_{\tau\in D(n-1)}\mathrm{sign}(\tau)(-i)^{n-1}\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{1+\zeta^{j-\tau(j)}}{1-\zeta^{j-\tau(j)}}
\\=&(-1)^{(n-1)/2}\sum_{\tau\in D(n-1)}\mathrm{sign}(\tau)\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{1+\zeta^{j+\tau(j)}}{1-\zeta^{j-\tau(j)}},
\end{align*}
where
$$D(n-1)=\{\tau\in S_{n-1}:\ \tau(j)\not=j\ \ \text{for all}\ j=1,\ldots,n-1\}.$$

Motivated by the above and [Question 403025](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/403025) of mine, I have formulated the following new conjecture.

**Conjecture.** Let $n>1$ be an odd number. Then
$$\sum_{\tau\in D(n-1)}\mathrm{sign}(\tau)\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{1+\zeta^{j-\tau(j)}}{1-\zeta^{j-\tau(j)}}=\frac{(-1)^{(n-1)/2}}n((n-2)!!)^2\tag{1}$$
for any primitive $n$-th root $\zeta$ of unity; in particular,
$$\det[f(j,k)]_{1\le j,k\le n-1}=\frac{((n-2)!!)^2}n\tag{2}$$
with $f(j,k)$ given by \eqref{1}.

My numerical computaton supports this conjecture.

**QUESTION.** Is the conjecture true? Can one supply a proof?

Answer (score 3):

The conjecture has been proved by my graduate student Han Wang and me via the Eigenvector-eigenvalue Identity, for our joint paper see http://arxiv.org/abs/2206.02589 .